# Export Local Group Policy Settings to Another Computer

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, workgroup

I have a problem that can solve, a client of mine have access free laptop for young people to research job or do paperwork. Those laptop cannot be on the domain. The administration of those computer is done via the "Veyon" application.

I create on each of them a user account with really strict Local Group Policy Settings and now I want to export those GPO to the other user on the 8 laptop.

To this end, I tried to manually copy them that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried export/import LGPO.exe but I think that only applied for the Computeur Policy not the User.

I'm sur that there is a simple solution but I can't fine it... So if someone as an idea it is most welcome!!! :D

Comment: `I also tried export/import LGPO.exe but I think that only applied for the Computeur Policy not the User.` LGPO works with user settings. That should be the correct tool.

Comment: Can you identify whether your problem is with the User policies EXPORT or with the IMPORT process?